# How to set the tab size of JTextPane

Tags: java, jtextpane

this is my text pane look like:
[image]

I want to be look like this:
[image]

How can i set the tab size of JTextPane?

Comment: [here's the answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757692/how-do-you-set-the-tab-size-in-a-jeditorpane)

Comment: @Mr.Yetti thanks for the link but it only cared for the first tab. I want to do is when i press tab in create white space , maybe 4 spaces.

Comment: The point is that when customizing `JEditorPane`/`JTextPane`s, you have to touch the underlying document. If you want to convert tabs into spaces, [try this one.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363784/setting-the-tab-policy-in-swings-jtextpane)